# Flutter Web Rich Text Editor

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am looking for a text editor similar to the one in the image.

[image]
I have seen an add-on that performs exactly what I want but is associated with the mobile keyboard.

In flutter web no keyboard opens, but you type directly.

That is why I would like to know if there is any solution to get what I am looking for, I am waiting for an answer, thank you very much for your attention.

**Here you have the plugin link:**
https://pub.dev/packages/zefyr
[image]

Comment: hey,Have you find anything like this? actually I am also looking for the same...

Comment: I still can't find a stable web repository, but you can look more here https://github.com/memspace/zefyr/issues/110

Comment: okay, thanks..I'll checkout

Comment: does this work with flutter web ??

Comment: You can find it here:
https://github.com/memspace/zefyr/issues/110

I didn't get it to work on the web.

Comment: I am also looking for a solution for flutter web

Comment: in the same boat as you guys... need a rich text editor that works in Flutter Web

Comment: There's this discussion, but so far nothing stable. https://github.com/memspace/zefyr/issues/222

Answer (score 1):

This will build for flutter web you need to make sure you are on `master branch` of `zephyr` and `flutter`

To change branch type in your console

```
flutter channel master

flutter channel upgrade
```

Hope this helps friends.

Patrick.